# Is it possible to convert a native iOS app to a web app?

Tags: ios, swift, web, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to convert a native iOS application for work. Does anyone know of any way to do this? I have thought about using the MobileFirst platform, but I don't know if this is possible even with that. I have seen many things about converting HTML5 into a Swift application, but not the other way around. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is written in Native code and you want it to now be in web code. There is no conversion tool to do that. You need to re-write your app in HTML, CSS, JavaScript and so on...

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am curious though as to why there are so many tools that can convert HTML5 into Swift but not the other way around?

Comment: These tools don't convert HTML to Swift. They make your app just display the WebApp in an `UIWebView`